# payment callback URL https with self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, payment, facebook-credits, credits

can the payment callback URL (https) work with self-signed certificate or do I need a commercial SSL cert ?

I did a quick check and the SSL connection from facebook to my server (default https port 443) fails during handshake, HTTP request is not even done.

As soon as I changed app configuration on FB to HTTP, everything works fine.

So far, everything else like canvas url etc. works just fine with self-signed cert, only having problems with payment callback URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a valid commercial cert (yes, costs a lot of money but there's some low cost SSL providers out there like GoDaddy.com).